# web.xml general tab Intellij

Tags: java, servlets, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have searched and searched, but i can't seem to find a thing, that should be pretty simple to find, i am following this guide on jetbrains homepage: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/specifying-the-servlet-initialization-parameters.html

And i cannot get past the first step: Open web.xml and switch to the General tab

I can open web.xml, but i cannot find the General tab, and that should be pretty simple, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an obsolete tutorial. When i click on General tab link, i get a 404... you have to edit your file by yourself or create a new J2EE project.

Comment: It seems that way, it is just weird that they have removed such a tool.

Comment: I was following a tutorial in eclipse our teacher gave us, but i wanted to do it in intellij, however in eclipse there was a design tab to the web.xml file, and not in intellij, so i did it manually :)

Answer (score 0):

The updated method to add Servlets & C. to web.xml for IntelliJ 2016.2 is explained at [configuring web app elements](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/creating-and-configuring-web-application-elements.html).

The idea is to right click on the top level node representing the web module and selecting from the contextual menu what you want to add, like a servlet.